# Cobra and existing conditions with new insurance in the future question

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, cobra

Hope this is an okay place to post this question...  So, I need to go to the doctor today but will be changing jobs as of next week and will have a period of time where I could potentially not be covered.  I have the option to elect COBRA coverage within the standard 60 days of the qualifying event, etc.  My question is, **if I go to the doctor today, while still covered by my previous insurance, then never got COBRA and payed out of pocket during the period where I would have no insurance, would my condition still be able to be covered by my new insurance when it kicks in?**  I know that if I received care without insurance during the "gap" that there is a chance that my condition would not be able to receive coverage on the new insurance.  I'm hoping I can go to the clinic today thus making it an existing condition.  Any help appreciated on this subject.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still covered as of the date of the doctors appointment, then the appointment will be covered under the rules of the old insurance company.

Please be careful regarding the timing because if the appointment then triggers a need for an x-ray, lab work, or prescription then the date for those medical events could take place outside the window of employer coverage. If the new coverage from the new employer hasn't kicked in yet, you will have to decide on paying for them without insurance coverage or electing to purchase COBRA coverage.

According the the current health care laws (including the affordable care act) you will be covered for pre-exsiting conditions if you go from:

- Company A - Company B
- Company A - COBRA - Company B
- Company A - small gap - Company B

The nice thing about COBRA is that you can retroactively decide to purchase it. So you may very well be under new coverage before you have to decide. The best for you is to have a small enough gap so that COBRA isn't needed.

Even if company A ends your coverage as of 5 PM Friday, you still have a window of time to settle the bills, and submit paperwork for reimbursement or to be paid from the Flex Spending account. Ask the insurance company how long you have, my experience has been that it is very large.

Comment: So, in other words.  As long as I see the doctor before my current coverage ends then I can see the doctor during the period of no coverage, pay out of pocket, but then be covered for the same condition a few months later when I have the new coverage?